# Can the same line of Node.js code run at the same time?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm pretty new to node and am trying to setup an express server.  The server will handle various requests and if any of them fail call a common failure function that will send e-mail. If I was doing this in something like Java I'd likely use something like a synchronized block and a boolean to allow the first entrance into the code to send the mail.

Is there anything like a synchronized block in Node? I believe node is single threaded and has a few helper threads to handle asyncronous/callback code. Is it at all possible that the same line of code could run at exactly the same time in Node?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give a concrete example?  This could be a complicated answer.  Node **is** single threaded, but there are mechanisms to introduce multi**processing** which might be what you are asking about.

Comment: For the part about the boolean to allow first entrance into the code, we would have to see your actual code to understand what you're really trying to accomplish.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Can the same line of Node.js code run at the same time? Is it at all possible that the same line of code could run at exactly the same time in Node?

No, it is not.  Your Javascript in node.js is entirely single threaded.  An event is pulled from the event queue.  That calls a callback associated with that event.  That callback runs until it returns.  No other events can be processed until that first one returns.  When it returns, the interpreter pulls the next event from the event queue and then calls the callback associated with it.

This does not mean that there are not concurrency issues in node.js.  There can be, but it is caused not by code running at the same physical time and creating conflicting access to shared variables (like can happen in threaded languages like Java).  Concurrency issues can be caused by the asynchronous nature of I/O in node.js.  In the asynchronous case, you call an asynchronous function, pass it a callback (or expect a promise in return).  Your code then continues on and returns to the interpreter.  Some time later an event will occur inside of node.js native code that will add something to the event queue.  When the interpreter is free from running other Javascript, it will process that event and then call your callback which will cause more of your code to run.

While all this is "in process", other events are free to run and other parts of your Javascript can run. So, the exposure to concurrency issues comes, not from simultaneous running of two pieces of code, but from one piece of your code running while another piece of your code is waiting for a callback to occur.  Both pieces of code are "in process".  They are not "running" at the same time, but both operations are waiting from something else to occur in order to complete.  If these two operations access variables in ways that can conflict with each other, then you can have a concurrency issue in Javascript.  Because none of this is pre-emptive (like threads in Java), it's all very predictable and is much easier to design for.

> Is there anything like a synchronized block in Node?

No, there is not.  It is simply not needed in your Javascript code.  If you wanted to protect something from some other asynchronous operation modifying it while your own asynchronous operation was waiting to complete, you can use simple flags or variables in your code.  Because there's no preemption, a simple flag will work just fine.

> I believe node is single threaded and has a few helper threads to handle asyncronous/callback code.

Node.js runs your Javascript as single threaded.  Internally in its own native code, it does use threads in order to do its work.  For example, the asynchronous file system access code internal to node.js uses threads for disk I/O.  But these threads are only internal and the result of these threads is not to call Javascript directly, but to insert events in the event queue and all your Javascript is serialized through the event queue.  Pull event from event queue, run callback associated with the event.  Wait for that callback to return.  Pull next event from the event queue, repeat...

> The server will handle various requests and if any of them fail call a common failure function that will send e-mail. If I was doing this in something like Java I'd likely use something like a synchronized block and a boolean to allow the first entrance into the code to send the mail.

We'd really have to see what your code looks like to understand what exact problem you're trying to solve. I'd guess that you can just use a simple boolean (regular variable) in node.js, but we'd have to see your code to really understand what you're doing.

Comment: @JohnCrux - Is this what you wanted to know?